# C# how get a value of richTextBox added to second form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, file-io, get

I write program. It's simple editor linke Notepad, created new form in main form, and I don't know how I can get and set value in the richTextField in sub form. When You click New file program use trah function.

```
private void NewWindow()
{
     Form2 f2 = new Form2();
     f2.MdiParent = this;
     f2.Text = "Document " + WindowNumber.ToString();
     WindowNumber++;
     f2.Show();
 }
```

When I have many open windows i don't can get to richTextBox in each of window.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, controls are added to forms with the protected acces modifier. Then, to get their values from outside you need to create a public property on each form to expose the text.

```
public string RichText{
    get{ return myTextBox.Text;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't quite get if you want the parent form to edit the children or the other way around.

if you want the parent to be able to edit the children then the children should expose a method like Oscar example to edit the `RichTextBox` and the parent should save the children somewhere:

```
List<Form2> frm = new List<Form2>();
private void NewWindow()
{
     Form2 f2 = new Form2();
     f2.MdiParent = this;
     f2.Text = "Document " + WindowNumber.ToString();
     WindowNumber++;
     f2.Show();
     frm.Add(f2);
}
```

if the child should edit the parent you have several ways to do it. probably the best one designedly is using Events:

```
  public delegate void EditHandler();
  public event EditHandler edit;
```